# Loading PDF from internal storage Error invalid format

Tags: java, android, pdf, internal, android-download-manager

So I've been practising download manager and i was trying out some program.
A first button will download a said Pdf to a location in my phone.
The second button is supposed to open the Pdf file with a Pdf reader installed by the user such as WP Reader etc..
The download works fine, but when i open the pdf , it says invalid format.
I uploaded a sample Pdf to the google drive , so I know that the uploaded file isnt corrupted in any case. There muse be some problem when the file is being downloaded from the server. Please help me find the mistake. And I am relatively new to Android.

And the download button uses an Onclicklistener while the loadPdf is given in the xml file android:onClick="downloadPdf" .

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String myHTTPUrl = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Pev9zz5bVjZTFFZ1dLZVp1WVU";
String TAG = "My app";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button download = (Button) findViewById(R.id.download);


    download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.v(TAG,"download method called");
            downloadPdf();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Listener Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v(TAG,"On Click Listener Called");

        }
    });

}


public void loadPdf(View view) {

    Log.v(TAG,"Pdf load called");

    File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/notes","ssp.pdf");
    if(pdfFile.exists())
    {
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
        Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(pdfIntent, "Open File");
        try
        {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Pdf not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

public void downloadPdf()
{
    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(myHTTPUrl));
    request.setTitle("Solid State Physics");
    request.setDescription("File is being Downloaded...");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/notes","ssp.pdf");
    manager.enqueue(request);

}}
```

EDITED : 
This is the exact error I'm facing with screenshot
Error : File format error , Cannot be opened
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlFsC.png).

Answer (score 0):

You're not downloading the PDF, you're downloading the *web-page* displaying the contents of the PDF. If you want to download the PDF file directly, use the following URL:

```
String myHTTPUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B5Pev9zz5bVjZTFFZ1dLZVp1WVU";
```

and your application should work.

(Don't forget to delete the invalid `notes/ssp.pdf` file first, otherwise the `DownloadManager` will download the file under a different name, like `notes/ssp-1.pdf`.)